# find and sort mongodb items - Nodejs , MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, find, mean-stack

I am new to development in the MEAN stack. This is the code I am using. Nodejs and MongoDB at backend. I am using MLAB for database.

```
{
    List.getListModelObject().find({ "specificList": specificList}, function (err, foundData) {
        if (err) {
            response = { success: false, message: err };
            callbackMethod(response, null);
            return;
        }

        if (foundData != null && foundData.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < foundData.length; i++) {
                listOfNumbers.push(foundData[i].listNum);
            }

            response = { success: true, message: "Successfuly retrieved List" };
            callbackMethod(response, listOfNumbers);
        }
    });

}
```

I want to add SORT() and I have searched this and other websites but am not able to use it correctly.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: on which field you want to sort the results?

Comment: specificList is the main field of the scope but i want to sort the list according to listNum.. so that listOfNumbers.push is done in ascending order. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think this link well cover your question a lot,
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Comment: thanks, so basically I should use the function like this: List.getListModelObject().find().sort({ "specificList": specificList}, function (err, foundData)   ?

Comment: just change the .sort... to ... sort({ "specificList": -1}) ( descending ) or  sort({ "specificList": 1}) ( ascending ) and you are good to go :D